# SQL query - joining two tables with a conditional

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For each area in my game I have many levels that can be achieved. Once a user earns a certain number of points in an area, his 'progress level' increases for that particular area. I have two tables in my database. One stores the progress of the user for a particular area of my game:

```
Table A

userID | areaID  | progressLevel | total points earnt
   1        1           1                1000
   1        2           1                 500
```

Another table, B, stores how many points are required to unlock increase the progress level

```
  areaID |  progressLevel  | points required
    1             2              5000
    1             3              9000
    1             4              11000
    2             2              9999
```

When enough points are achieved by the user then I check table B and increase the progress level of the user in table A.  For example, if user 1 earns over 5000 points in area `1`, I would update table A and set progress level = `2`.

My problem is I want to write a query to obtain, for a particular user, all their progress levels for each area as well as the number of points required for the next level. For example, for user with id 1, I would like:

```
areaID | progressLevelCurrent | total points earnt | points required for next progress level
   1                1                 1000                        4000
   2                1                 500                         9499
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    areaID,
    progressLevel AS CurrentLevel,
    `total points earnt` as TotalNow,
    (
        SELECT (pointsTilNext - TableA.TotalNow) 
        FROM TableB
        WHERE TableB.progressLevel = (TableA.progressLevel+1)
    ) AS ToNextLevel

FROM TableA
WHERE userID = ##
```

Edited to add:

You could also use a join, which would be a more efficient use of server capacity.  The left join will return a result for a person even if the person is at the highest level, ie there is no row matching `TableA.progressLevel+1`

```
SELECT
    areaID,
    progressLevel AS CurrentLevel,
    `total points earnt` as TotalNow,
    (pointsTilNext - TableA.TotalNow) AS ToNextLevel

FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.progressLevel = (TableA.progressLevel+1)
WHERE userID = ##
```

Comment: A sub-query really isn't necessary here, and will negatively impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
select A.areaID, A.progressLevel as progressLevelCurrent, A.`total points earnt`, B.`points required` - A.`total points earnt` as `points required for next progress level`
from A
    inner join B on A.areaID = B.areaID and (A.progressLevel + 1) = B.progressLevel
where B.`points required` > A.`total points earnt`;
```

Comment: I prefer the other method on the basis that when the user reaches the maximum progress level, the row wouldn't show up at all in this query, I think

Comment: You could accomplish the same thing by adding a WHERE clause (see my edited answer) and your performance would be better than it would with a sub-query.